# Order By before a Group By

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need to pull some data on a couple thousand records, but I'm having trouble sorting the results.

```
SELECT IdCode, GROUP_CONCAT(' ',CONCAT(MONTHNAME(ei.StartDatetime),' ',YEAR(ei.StartDatetime))) 
FROM exclusion_import_data eid JOIN exclusion_import ei ON ei.ImportId = eid.ImportId 
WHERE ( IdCode IN ( '84277', '253533' ))  
GROUP BY IdCode 
ORDER BY RecordId ASC;
```

Basically I'm trying to see which months specific records appeared in our system.

> 253533     May 2013, November 2013, December 2013, January 2014, February
>   2014, March 2014, April 2014, May 2014, June 2014, August 2014,
>   October 2013, September 2013, June 2013, July 2013, May 2013, August
>   2013 84277     September 2013, April 2014, May 2013, May 2014, June 2014,
>   May 2013, March 2014, June 2013, February 2014, January 2014, July
>   2013, December 2013, November 2013, August 2013, October 2013, August
>   2014

The above query returns the correct months, separated by the idCodes, but the months are all out of order.

How can I sort the records before grouping them?

Comment: Mgmt summary: you can `group_concat(myfield ORDER BY myfield ASC)`, so in your case add `ORDER BY ei.StartDateTime` to the `group_concat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an ordering within the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, for example:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(ei.StartDatetime,'%M %Y') ORDER BY ei.StartDatetime) 
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(My preference would be to get the month and year with a single function call, and one reference to the column, rather than three function calls and two references to the same column. I've demonstrated that above as well.)

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1):

Use the `order by` option *in* the `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT IdCode,
       GROUP_CONCAT(' ', CONCAT(MONTHNAME(ei.StartDatetime),' ',YEAR(ei.StartDatetime))
                    ORDER BY ei.StartDatetime)
FROM exclusion_import_data eid JOIN
     exclusion_import ei
     ON ei.ImportId = eid.ImportId 
WHERE ( IdCode IN ( '84277', '253533' ))
GROUP BY IdCode 
ORDER BY RecordId ASC;
```